# Potato or Potatoes

Tags: numbers, quantifiers, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

When considering a recipe which contains potatoes, which would be correct for the UK:

1. 350g of potato
2. 350g of potatoes

Comment: That depends on whether you need 350 g of entire, separable potatoes, or a 350 g potato mass (mashed potatoes, for example).

Comment: Lets that the type of potato is uncertain, it could be possible that it is a singular 100g potato or several potatoes to make up 100g.

Comment: As backgammon mentions below "potato" may be right in some cases, but "potatoes" will always be right. So there's no need to use "potato".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potato:

potato [pəˈteitəu] noun — plural poˈtatoes

a type of plant with round underground stems (called tubers) which are used as a vegetable

Plural is Potatoes. Ex: I like potatoes.

Possessive is Potato's. Ex: Peel the potato's skin.

Hope this help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what form the potatoes will be used in, *potatoes* would be more appropriate. *Potato* as a mass noun is quite uncommon unless you're referring to the entire crop, as in "I plant ten acres of potato every year."

In addition, if you're listing ingredients, you'd generally list them in a form which the average person is likely to acquire, and specify processing in the recipe, as in "150g of green bell peppers, chopped." I haven't ever seen (fresh) potatoes sold as an undifferentiated mass, and your cooks won't have, either.

"Potato, 350g" would also be acceptable.

Comment: _Potato_ may be uncommon in agricultural usage but the question is in a culinary context. A recipe might refer to the raw (quantised) vegetable but could equally mean a potato mash or grated potato. The list item given by the OP might be from a shopping list (in which potatoes is appropriate) or from [_mise en place_](http://reluctantgourmet.com/cooking-techniques/more-specific-techniques/item/53-let%E2%80%99s-talk-about-mise-en-place) when potato is definitely to be preferred.

Comment: @Fortiter: Fair enough, but if this is a culinary question, perhaps it could have been asked on [cooking.SE]. :^)

Comment: "Potato may be uncommon in agricultural usage but the question is in a culinary context." - I think you're missing the point of that explanation. `Potato` as a mass noun is uncommon in _every_ usage, but less uncommon than usual in agriculture. If the recipe referred to a potato mash or grated potato, even for mise en place, you'd still specify it as "350g of potatoes, mashed/grated."

Answer (score 0):

Volume:
Cubed peeled potato 350 ml

Also in the name of a recipe:
Curry Beef and Potato

As used in the case mentioned above, grams refers to weight, not listed the same as when referring to ingredients by volume or item:
Baby potatoes, larger ones cut in half 350 grams
Instant mashed potatoes, 1 box (350 grams)

For a recipe, singular or plural is used when quantity refers to part of one whole ingredient (item) or several individual ones:
1/2 potato, shredded (150 grams)
1 medium potato 
2 large potatoes

Even if these terms could be considered grammatically incorrect, they are now commonly published in this manner.